# Difference between 'Related work' and 'comparison methods' sections?

Tags: publications, writing

I have a method and I want to compare this with some existing ones. To my understanding, these existing methods can be regarded as 'Comparison methods'. But where should I briefly describe these comparison methods? putting them in 'related work' will be appropriate??
To me, related work section describes *overall* picture of research field. But in my recent paper, reviewer told that I should compare my method will *all* methods that I put in related work section. This is confusing.
So what is the difference between these two sections?
And, some papers put related work section in the end of paper. If I follow this and put comparison methods in related work, then how can I perform 'results and discussion' without briefly explaining those methods. Please help me get out of this confusion (CS and SE background)

Comment: Where are you currently describing the methods you compare against?

Comment: @GoodDeeds this is my main problem. Where to describe the method you compare against? would this be appropriate if i directly put methods in experimental section and do the comparison. And in the related work section, i describe working of those methods and their caveats?